# Using jquery, how can i find if an image exists with a certain attribute that is within a div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

If i have the following html:

```
<div id="container">
           <img personId="12" src"Joe.png" />
           <img personId="16" src"Scott.png" />
           <img personId="17" src"Bill.png" />
</div>
```

Is it possible to:

1. Return a list of personIds that exist from the images inside that container div
2. Have a function that can search if a certain number exists in the image list (looking at the same attribute)

I tried using find() but that didn't seem to work

Comment: Just a snotty comment; try not to use non-standard attributes, you can change "personId" to "data-personid" and be html compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting all the values you can use `.map()` method:

```
var ids = $('#container img[personId]').map(function(){
   return this.getAttribute('personId');
}).get();
```

And for checking the existence of a value you can use `$.inArray()` utility function.

```
if ( $.inArray(id, ids) > -1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery use the `attr` function:

```
arr = [];
$('#container')
  .children()
  .each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).attr('personId'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery attr() method..

```
jQuery('img').each(function(){
    _IMG = jQuery(this);
    var pid = _IMG.attr('personId');
    console.log(pid);
});
```

For the search function, I would guess something like:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var pidToSearchFor = 17;
    jQuery('img').each(function(index){
        _IMG = jQuery(this);
        var pid = _IMG.attr('personId');

        if(PERSONS.isSame(pid)) {
            console.log("FOUND! IN IMAGE NO."+index)}

    });


});

var PERSONS = {
toSearchFor = 17,
isSame: function(pidIn) {
        _IMG = jQuery(this);
        if (toSearchFor == pidIn) {return true}
        else {return false}


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Adopting undefined's selector

```
function getPersonIdList()
{
    var personIdList = new Array();
    var personIds = $("#container img[personId]").each(
            function()
            {
                personIdList[personIdList.length] = $(this).attr("personId");
            });

    return personIdList;
}

function isPersonIdExists(personId)
{
    var personIds = $("#container img[personId='" + personId + "']");
    if (personIds.length > 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```